# Поместить значение из Combobox в функцию

Tags: c#, winforms

Вопрос, есть комбобокс, в котором происходит выбор текстового варианта. Необходимо сделать так, чтобы выбранный текстовый вариант соответствовал определенному числу и помещался в качестве переменной в функцию. Например, вариантам: чай, кофе - соответствует число 100, вариантам: лимонад, сок число 200. Сами числа не видны в комбобоксе. Мне пришло в голову, присвоить вариантам из одной группы какое-то id и потом считывать его при помощи регулярного выражения(но как спрятать это id?). Может есть более простое решение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У `Combobox`, есть свойство `ValueMember`.

Допустим, у тебя есть `List<Product> list` в котором содержится коллекция вида Name|Id
Ты делаешь следующее:

```
Combobox.DataSource=list;
Combobox.DisplayMember="Name";
Combobox.ValueMember="Id";
```

Если ты пользуешься VS2015, то  можно сделать ,немного, красивее, избавившись от строковых литералов,

```
Combobox.DataSource=list;
Combobox.DisplayMember=nameof(Product.Name);
Combobox.ValueMember=nameof(Product.Id);
```

В итоге получается, что отображается какое-то имя, а в `SelectedValue` твой `Id`

Comment: Спасибо, идею понял. Я добавлял в комбобокс элементы через comboBox.Items.AddRange(new object[] {}); Я так понял, надо в классе Product описать функционал и уже в комбобокс добавлять коллекцию типа Product, так?

Comment: @cruim, List<> я привел для примера. Можно тоже самое через Dictionary<T,T> сделать. В любом случае нужен какой-то контейнер.

Comment: Сделал все по схеме(использовал лист), запускаю - все работает. Но при попытке зайти в дизайнер формы выдает ошибку Failed to parse method 'InitializeComponent'. The parser reported the following error 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'. Please look in the Task List for potential errors.

Comment: @cruim, если у тебя дизайнер формы поломался, то ты где-то накосячил. Возможно, ты лазил в методе InitializeComponent и что-то там поломал...

Comment: насколько я понял, эти строки Combobox.DataSource=list;
Combobox.DisplayMember=nameof(Product.Name);должны быть прописаны в методе InitializeComponent, так? если закоментить эти изменения, дизайнер работает.

Comment: InitializeComponent - это метод, который генерится системой и выполняет начальную инициализацию компонентов на форме и его лучше не трогать... Лучше в Form.cs объявить все необходимое и в вокнструкторе Form1() после метода InitializeComponent вызвать свои методы инициализации.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45206/discussion-between-cruim-and-iluxa1810).